# Excel - VBA - Concatenate - Multiple Cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have a code to concatenate three columns in a difference sheet for one cell -

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2") = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2") & 
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2") & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")
```

I want to repeat this cell for n number of time in the excel sheet - not able to do that

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have stored your numbers in columns A, B, C.

First, use this code to determine last row (1 stands for A column):

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then use `For` loop to achieve what you after (1 stands for A column, 2 - B, 3 - C, D - 4):

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + Cells(i, 2).Value + Cells(i, 3).Value
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

In this routine `n` is the last row you want to be filled:

```
Sub KonKat()
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    n = 5

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        For i = 2 To n
            .Range("D" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value & .Range("B" & i).Value & .Range("C" & i).Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks  gary this thing worked - one more help - Can assign this code to a certain button - Pardon me i think its too silly